# Problem with putting text into nested div tags

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put text into nested div's and it works for some but not for all. When I try to put the text where its not working it forces the other div elements down a line.I had a previous version of this where I nested them the same way and didn't have this problem.  Any idea where I went wrong?

```css
    /* my css for the divs */
div.mycard{
    background-color: beige;
    width: 400px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-left: 75%;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
div.cardcost{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 30px;
    height: 35px;
}
div.hscardepic{
    background-color: rgb(233, 27, 233);
    height: 35px;
    width: 5px;
}
div.cardamount{
    background-color: black;
    width: 30px;
    height: 35px;
    z-index: 11;
    margin-left: 8000%;
}
p.cardname{
    z-index: 12;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
    <!-- These divs are nested in another div with display: inline-block to put them next to text-->
<div class="mycard">
    <div class="cardcost">
        <div class="hscardepic">
            <div class="cardamount">
                <p style="margin-left: 5px;color: white;">&times;2</p>
            </div>
         </div>  
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The major issue that's hiding your paragraph is caused by `margin-left: 8000%;` in `div.cardamount` which is pushing the div outside the viewport

There is another issue with class `cardname` is not set on the `p` element so your CSS rules are not applied

here's a fixed version https://jsfiddle.net/xr271aen/1/

Comment: I had the margin that high to push it from ontop of the cardcost and hscardepic classes. At 8% it sits directly ontop of them. Any idea on how to get it to go to the right side of the container without using such a high margin percent?

Answer (score 0):

Simple use flex method...
And I slightly changed your html code :)

```css
    /* my css for the divs */
div.mycard{
background-color: beige;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    display: flex;
}
div.cardcost{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 30%;
    height: 35px;
}
div.hscardepic{
    background-color: rgb(233, 27, 233);
    height: 35px;
    width: 20%;
}
div.cardamount{
    background-color: black;
    width: 20%;
    height: 35px;
    z-index: 11;
    margin-left: 0;
}
p.cardname{
    z-index: 12;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
    <!-- These divs are nested in another div with display: inline-block to put them next to text-->
<div class="mycard">
    <div class="cardcost">
      <p style="margin-left: 5px;color: white;">&times;1</p>
     </div> 
        <div class="hscardepic">
          <p style="margin-left: 5px;color: white;">&times;2</p>
         </div>   
            <div class="cardamount">
                <p style="margin-left: 5px;color: white;">&times;3</p>
            </div>
         
     
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am still running into trouble when trying to put text into the mycard div. I fixed up the margins from what you had cause i wanted the cardcost and hscardepic classes next to each other and the cardamount to the right end of the container. When I put text into the mycard div and outside of the other div's it pushes them all over the place. It honestly makes no sense to me cause I have the previous version and it works fine, the only thing that is different is the fact I have the mycard div and another div for text nested in a disply: inline-block div.